# CountIF Function: Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to figure if Countifs function would be the correct function for the problem I am trying to solve. Within the image you can see I have four columns. I am trying to count how many Yes answers I have for the specific person listed in the A and it be counted in the D column. I would like to be able to show the count YTD. Example: Sophie row 24 was compliant on that date, in column D, I would like the count of how many times she was compliant YTD up until that date. I want the count to be specific to that person, if possible. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

I have searched through multiple articles in regards to using the countifs with multiple values and arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Using your desired `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,"<="&B2,$B$2:$B$11,">="&DATE(2023,1,1),$C$2:$C$11,"Yes")
```

Result:

[image]

Also you can use `SUM` and multiplication only:

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11<=B2)*($B$2:$B$11>=DATE(2023,1,1))*($C$2:$C$11="Yes"))
```